# How to validate email before send mail and finding whether the mail send - django

Tags: django

I use - is_valid = validate_email(e) for validating email. It can detect if '@' is not present or some more but not providing whether the email entered is active now. AND I used sendmail for sending email. I used try except block. Mail is sending but sometimes try code running and someother times except block is running. How to avoid this abnormal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

if i correctly understand your question..
There is an option called emailfield in djangoforms.it will show validation error if @ is not present.

```
field_name = forms.EmailField(**options)
```

Comment: I am not using forms and i am working to make API. Can u pls suggest for api